# what would be my rails URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a rails app located at [home]/rails_apps/final/final2 on my Bluehosts server. I run script/server here with ssh/shell..

```
actionen@actionengineers.com [~/rails_apps/final/final2]# script/server -e production
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/actionen/rails_apps/final/final2/app/controllers/items_controller.rb:87: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
/home/actionen/rails_apps/final/final2/app/controllers/shelves_controller.rb:84: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

I am not able to see my site at http://actionengineers.com:3000. what is my url?!

Comment: Are you sure the the actionengineers.com URL maps to the actual machine you started the app on?  Can you get the machiens IP and then try to access http://ip.address:3000.  Also is there any firewall on the machine which may be blocking port 3000.

Comment: How can i find out bout firewall settings from cpanel for ssh/shell?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with how you've started Mongrel. 0.0.0.0 is the wildcard address; it means that the server will listen on all available interfaces, even ones that are brought up after the server starts.

actionengineers.com resolves to 69.89.27.235. Is this the IP address for your server? Run `ifconfig -a` and ensure the IP matches.

If it does, you probably have a firewall issue. [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) is the most common way to set up a firewall on Linux, though it is by no means the only way. Run `iptables -L INPUT` as root to see the existing rules for incoming packets. In particular, look at the first line for the default policy. If it's DROP, then any packets that don't match a rule are dropped.

Comment: I've delete my answer, because it's clearly wrong now. So I'm going to leave my response to your comment here: It seems you're correct about 0.0.0.0. I just assumed that binding to the wrong IP the problem. Adding the -b option is how I solved this problem in the past. But it turns turns that was because older versions of script/server bound to 127.0.0.1 by default.

Answer (score 0):

If the firewall passes this port outside, your url should be http://:3000 or http://:3000
Do not forget open 3000 port in your firewall

Comment: how do i do it from cpanel or ssh/shell?